# Explaining amortized analysis on dynamic array

Tags: big-o, dynamic-arrays, amortized-analysis

So I have been struggling with amortized analysis on dynamic arrays. I have studied through the University of Torontos slides on this topic and this

> 

When the array is ½ full after DELETE, create a new

array of half of the size, and copy all the elements.

Consider the following sequence of operations

performed on a full array with n element…

APPEND, DELETE, APPEND, DELETE, APPEND, …

Ɵ(n) amortized cost per operation since every

APPEND or DELETE causes allocation > > > of new array.

especially does not make sense to me.

Is it O(n) because every append and delete operation is dependent on how big n is? But even then, do the costs not increase in a constant manner?

Appreciate any help!